# Ruby Nokogiri extract HTML tab value

Tags: html, css, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

there's a webpage with many pages. And I'd like to know the total pages for each search.
Like the pictures shown below. Since the last page is page 41 and it becomes un_clickable. So I want to extract that value 41 from those 2 span tags.

Any help?
I tried with xpath. But would prefer a CSS solution

Thanks

```
page_temp = Nokogiri::HTML(browser.html)  
page_temp.xpath('tr[@td = "colspan="32""]').each do |node|
    puts node.text
```

[Click here to view the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tczpd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Ruby here's a simple code you can use

```
page_temp = Nokogiri::HTML(browser.html)  
all_pages = page_temp.search("td[colspan='32'] tr td")
puts all_pages.map{|p| p.text}  # list all page numbers
puts all_pages.last.text        # list the last page number
```